How to get old Android Studio plugin "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)"?
I am working on a project where it is crucial to have the old scenform, everything works well until today I wanted to add a new 3d file to my project. To make an asset I would need "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)", but it is not available in the plugin menu in Android Studio. How can I get it or is it possible to not need to use it?
I use Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1. The only other question about this was 6 years old and could not help me.

Just making sure you are aware of https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android and the successor https://github.com/SceneView/sceneview-android
